# Como mostrar uma mensagem de confirmação após verificação no servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlet

Boa tarde pessoal!
Ao clicar no botão de Alterar, realizo uma verificação para ver se os dados no banco continuam os mesmos. Como faço para retornar uma janela de confirmação, caso os resultados não sejam os mesmos?

Exemplo: Seleciono o material que quero alterar, preencho os inputs, mas antes de clicar em Alterar, saio da mesa por algum motivo, e outro usuário, em outro computador, altera este mesmo material.
Quando eu voltar e clicar em Alterar, faz a verificação dos dados, como faço para mostrar uma mensagem informando que os dados foram alterados e perguntando se mesmo assim eu desejo alterar?

Desde já agradeço :)

Answer (score 0):

Você teria que salvar o status atual do objeto no começo da transação Ex:

Ao começar o fluxo de alteração, você coloca o obj a ser alterado em formato json na view em uma hidden algo assim para depois validar ele novamente no back-end...

Se no seu objeto é salvo tem data e hora da alteração, pode simplesmente colocar este campo como hidden e validar se é igual ao alterado porem desta maneira não irá saber o que foi alterado.

Comment: Blz amigo, mas minha dúvida na verdade é: após realizar a validação, como mandar esta informação ao jsp e abrir uma janela informando que foi alterado e perguntando se mesmo assim deseja alterar... isso que está pegando.... a validação já está tranquila... Obrigado